# List of theorems by number of proofs

Tags: reference-works

Has anyone ever attempted a list of theorems ranked by the number of published proofs?  Maybe such a table could have a column listing the number of known proofs (although it may be optimistic to think that any count is complete).

A guess:

1. Pythagorean theorem
2. Law of quadratic reciprocity
3. Algebraic closure of the field of complex numbers (known as the fundamental theorem of algebra, but some object to that name as a misnomer that may confuse students)
4. ???
5. $\cdots\cdots$

Comment: Looks like someone just came from the FToA question :).

Comment: the $\zeta(2)$ computation has several popular proofs, as does the PNT (there are nearly infinite equivalent formulations of the PNT)

Comment: [A relevant link.](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Wagon601-617.pdf)

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is "no" or somebody would have said something.

Comment: Generally, when creating a new tag, it is useful to create also tag-wiki; so that other users know what the tag is intended for. (I suppose that the tag ([tag:refernce-works]) was created in this questions, since it is the oldest question having this tag.)

Comment: Thanks for [writing the tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/870178/revisions), Michael Hardy.